# Add more verbosity when running `fsck` disk check at boot time?

Tags: fsck

I've set the  number of mounts after which the filesystem will be checked for errors:

`sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/nvme0n1p2`

(More at https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-force-fsck-to-check-filesystem-after-system-reboot-on-linux).

This causes `fsck` to run on every boot.

I've also added a script `/root/fsck-log-save.sh` to save each `fsck` log:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /run/initramfs/fsck.log "/tmp/fsck.log.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
```

(The script must be executable: `sudo chmod +x /root/fsck-log-save.sh`)

In order to run this log saving script on each boot, create a service `/etc/systemd/system/fsck-log-rename.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=FSCK log save at startup.

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/fsck-log-save.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service:

`sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/fsck-log-rename.service`

and start it:

`sudo systemctl start fsck-log-rename.service`

I'd like to have a more verbose output from `fsck` written into `fsck.log`. There is an option `-V`, but where to add this option?

Comment: I would assume that is not going to work: `-v` needs to be issued when the command is issued. `systemd-fsck-root.service ` does the systemcheck  and edit the command there to include ``-v` and you also will need to edit `/etc/fstab`  and set `passno` to 0 on each boot (as that is the trigger to do a file system check). See `man systemd-fsck`.  OR you will also need a personal systemd service for your system check.